# $_FILES undefined index error

Tags: php, file-upload

i check all topics in stack about files and undefined index error but cant find answer anywhere. I have two files:

wpis.html

```
    <form action="wpis.php" method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

wpis.php

```
if($_POST["Submit"])
{
echo $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
}
```

And every time i'm getting this error : Undefined index: file in... 
I tried it on my computer using intellij plugin and on local host using wamp server with uploadfiles turn on. And ideas what may be the problem?

Comment: With `enctype="multipart/form-data"` added, your code works so this can not be reproduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the proper enctype in your form tag:

```
<form action="wpis.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try ( this was geared towards multiple file uploads but should still work ) - but as @Schlaus said - the form must have the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` set when uploading files.

```
foreach( $_FILES['file']['name'] as $i => $name ) {
    if( !empty( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i] ) ) {
        $name = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
        $size = $_FILES['file']['size'][$i];
        $type = $_FILES['file']['type'][$i];
        $tmp  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];

        echo $name,$size,$type,$tmp;
    }
}
```

**↓↓ Working example ↓↓**

```
html
----

<!-- target is in the same directory as html running upload form -->
<form action="upload_target.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h1>Standard File Upload</h1>
    <input type="file" name="file[]">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>



<?php
    /* upload_target.php */

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

        $fieldname='file';

        define('NL',PHP_EOL);

        foreach( $_FILES[$fieldname]['name'] as $i => $name ) {
            if( !empty( $_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'][$i] ) ) {

                $name = $_FILES[$fieldname]['name'][$i];
                $size = $_FILES[$fieldname]['size'][$i];
                $type = $_FILES[$fieldname]['type'][$i];
                $tmp  = $_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'][$i];

                echo '<pre>',$name,NL,$size,NL,$type,NL,$tmp,'</pre>';
            }
        }   
    }
?>
```

> output
>
> ---
>
> ```
> 6a00d8341d65de53ef01156f9b94a1970b-320wi.jpg
> 21714
> image/jpeg
> C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\uploadtemp\php22AF.tmp
> ```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: files in C:\Users\Piotrek\Desktop\www\ProjektPHP\wpis.php on line 69

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Users\Piotrek\Desktop\www\ProjektPHP\wpis.php on line 69

form :     <form action="wpis.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file">
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
        </form>

Comment: sorry, i had `files` rather than `file`

Comment: still nothing, is this language is so dumb or what?

Comment: one last suggestion before I go to bed, as the loop suggests an array try using `file[]` as the name of the input element - ie: `<input type='file' name='file[]' />`

Comment: I changed name from file to file[] but errow with "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" still appear, the second one with invalid index too. Any ideas what is the reason this problem?